# Process exits when Startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput is set true

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, process, tfs

I am trying to develop a console application which performs tfs merge.Command to execute is:

**tf merge $/CodeBase/ALPHA $/CodeBase/BETA /recursive /version:C4~C6**

When there is a conflict  in the merge operation , an error is raised first and a resolve conflict window appeas where i resolve conflicts . After i resolve conflicts , final output is displayed.

c# code is as follows for console application which performs tf merge:

```
Process proc = new Process();                
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tf.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = " merge $/CodeBase/ALPHA $/CodeBase/BETA /version:C4~C6";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
string line1 = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
string line2 = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

**Problem :**

The process exits abrupty showing only the initial error message . Ideally it should wait until i resolve all the conflicts and the process will wait until then. 
But since i am setting  *proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;* ,application is not waiting for resolve conflict window (not even starting it). But if i comment this line ,it is working correctly , but i am not able to read final output.

Help me please.

EDIT : 7/23

I believe i am doing asynchronous read operation (may be that could be problem). Is there a way by which i can perform synchronous read???

Comment: Why not wrap the code around a `try{}catch{}` and properly trap the exception

Comment: I have put this code inside a try -catch . But no exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach eventhandlers
    proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => ErrorLine(e.Data);
    proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => OutputLine(e.Data);

```
void ErrorLine(string text)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    Console.Error.WriteLine(text);
    Console.ResetColor();
}
void OutputLine(string text)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: This doesnt solve problem :(   . Still when i comment RedirectStandardError = true; , resolve conflict window shows. if not , it does not show still .  Is it because i am performing asynchronous read operation ?. Is there a way by which i can synchronously wait for output response.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with TFS which executes with '/noprompt' if it detects a stdout redirection.
Problem was solved by setting environment variable TFS_IGNORESTDOUTREDIRECT=1.